# Longest list of celebrity names

Tags: knowledge

My friend sent me this great puzzle. What is the longest list of celebrity names you can make where each surname is the given name of the next celebrity? For example:

> Clive James Dean Martin Lawrence

Can you do better? To make things easier, let's define a celebrity as someone who has a Wikipedia page about them. The same person/name cannot be used more than once.

EDIT: After receiving the first few answers I realized that there are probably too many celebrities out there. So let's restrict the list to **just actors**.

Comment: Continuing from yours... Lawrence Taylor James Oliver Sean Parker .... It's not too difficult to find first names that are also last names and there are plenty of names on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ooooh very nice. Well post it as an answer and see how many we can get. Perhaps we should limit the celebrities to a particular field?

Comment: Note that James Oliver is usually Jamie Oliver. By the way you can add Parker Posey on the end of that :)

Comment: There are at least 7 "James Oliver"s on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Oliver

Comment: I’m voting to close this as [open-ended](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/5373).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Seconded as it currently stands, but could it be considered less open-ended if Dmitry set a specific target for people to reach - say, the first answer to reach 50? Would that be a better way to run with a question that is typically seen as 'open-ended' - by closing off the end?! Interested in your opinion (and that of the community via that meta post you linked to), thanks.

Comment: I just changed it to actors. I think it will give us a nice set to work with. Alternatively I can make it first to 50 or whatever the threshold is. Happy to go either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Current total: 73**

> Kristen Stewart, Stewart Donald, Donald Stewart, Stewart Lee, Lee Mack, Mack David, David James, James Taylor, Taylor Gabriel, Gabriel Axel, Axel Alonso, Alonso Edward, Edward Albert, Albert Anastasia, Anastasia Ashley, Ashley Cole, Cole Anthony, Anthony Joshua, Joshua Allen, Allen Arthur, Arthur Alexander, Alexander Arnold, Arnold Clark, Clark Smith, Smith Joseph, Joseph Arthur, Arthur John, John Lennon, Lennon Murphy, Murphy Jensen, Jensen Kyra, Kyra Davis, Davis Daniel, Daniel Craig, Craig Charles, Charles Kennedy, Kennedy Edwin, Edwin Abbey, Abbey Lincoln, Lincoln Jean-Marie, Jean-Marie Andre, Andre Carter, Carter Elliott, Elliot Arnold, Arnold Allen, Allen Frances, Frances Cleveland, Cleveland Gary, Gary Neville, Neville Alexander, Alexander Adam, Adam Ant, Ant Henson, Henson Barnes, Barnes Murphy, Murphy Lee, Lee Aaron, Aaron Douglas, Douglas Graham, Graham Fraser, Fraser Ellis, Ellis Franklin, Franklin Thomas, Thomas Watson, Watson Duncan, Duncan Allan, Allan Dell, Dell Henderson, Henderson Bryan, Bryan Dick, Dick Dale, Dale Eve, Eve Frank     **TBC**

Answer (score 4):

I can make

> an infinite one with [James Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Stewart) and [Stewart James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_James). Perhaps it's even possible to make one with a single chain...

Comment: Ah good catch! I just modified the problem so you cannot reuse the same name.

Comment: "Perhaps it's even possible to make one with a single chain..." Depending on your definition of "celebrity", [yes it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Neville).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Kelly

Answer (score 3):

#### Current celebrity count: 68

> Clive James Dean Martin Lawrence Taylor James Oliver Sean Parker Posey Lester Pearson Jordan Patrick Stewart Bradley Allen Morris Abram Ryan Nelsen Ned Kelly Brook Lee Perry Mason Morgan Stanley Bruce Willis Reed Brody Nelson Norman Lindsay Graham Norton Otis Lord Tim Noah Gordon Ramsay MacDonald Carey Grant Nicholas Brendon Leonard Murray Melvin Calvin Harris Doran Clark Blaise Alexander Arnold Ross Lynch Cooper Rush Holt Ashley Cole Luke Norris... This could go on for a while.

The strategy is

> to find first names that are also last names (which is very common among male given names since in earlier parts of history, last names were taken from the father's name).

Comment: this is great work! But what would happen if you restrict the celebrities to just actors?

Answer (score 2):

I already answered but this one is with just actors

**Current Total: 23**

> Victor Aaron, Aaron Paul, Paul Douglas, Douglas Tait, Tait Fletcher, Fletcher Sheridan, Sheridan Earl Russell, Russell Todd, Todd Allen, Allen Garfield, Garfield Morgan, Morgan Kelly, Kelly Rowan, Rowan Joseph, Joseph Will, Will Kat, Kat Graham, Graham Martin, Martin Lawrence, Lawrence Olivier, Olivier Pierre, Pierre Brice, Brice Bexter **TBC**

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from eyl327's answer:

**Current celebrity count : 18**

> Clive James Dean Martin Lawrence Taylor James Oliver Sean Parker Posey Lester Young Vivian Vance Joy Reid Scott Adams